# Can this logic be simplified?

Tags: c#, logic, isenabled, isnullorempty

I've got 2 groups of controls.

The first one contains 3 textboxes named a, b and c. They can all be enabled or disabled at the same time.

The second group contains 2 textboxes (d and e). One and only one is enabled at a time.

Now, I have a boolean variable (named ok), which is true if:

- At least one of a,b and c is enabled AND contains text
- The enabled second group's textbox contains text
- None can be enabled WITHOUT containing text

And I want to check it **all in one call**.

Here's what I get:

```
bool ok =
(
    (
        (
            (!a.IsEnabled ||
                (a.IsEnabled && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a.Text))) &&
            (!b.IsEnabled ||
                (b.IsEnabled && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(b.Text))) &&
            (!c.IsEnabled ||
                (c.IsEnabled && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.Text))) &&
            (a.IsEnabled || b.IsEnabled || c.IsEnabled)
        )
    ) &&
    (
        (!d.IsEnabled ||
            (d.IsEnabled && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d.Text))) &&
        (!f.IsEnabled ||
            (f.IsEnabled && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f.Text)))
    )
);
```

It's quite heavy on the eye, any idea on how to simplify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not stick all your controls into a list an query them using LINQ

```
var group1 = new[] { a, b, c };
var group2 = new[] { d, e };
var all = group1.Concat(group2);
// assuming all controls are the same or implement the same interface
Func<ControlType, bool> enabledAndNotEmpty = (x) => {
    return x.IsEnabled && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Text);
};
Func<ControlType, bool> enabledAndEmpty = (x) => {
    return x.IsEnabled && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Text);
};
var ok = group1.Any(enabledAndNotEmpty) && // a, b or c is enabled & not empty
         group2.Any(enabledAndNotEmpty) && // d or e is enabled & not empty
         !all.Any(enabledAndEmpty); // none of the above are enabled & empty
```

Comment: That doesn't quite do the same as the code from the question: Imagine `a`, `b` and `d` were enabled - then `a` and `d` could contain non-empty text, while `b` could be empty, and your code would still set `ok` to `true`, even though the code from the question does not allow enabled text boxes to be empty.

Comment: Eh, so you want me to have that many more calls to implement new variables? :p

Comment: @O.R.Mapper perhaps I've misinterpreted the question but the requirements as I read them were both groups must have *at least* one control that is both enabled and not empty - the above code gives that. Kilazur I'd hardly call it *many more* calls, it's moving all your controls into a *queryable* array, if your array grows this would be *much* easier to maintain / update.

Comment: Edited my question, I indeed missed a criteria.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
!a.IsEnabled || (a.IsEnabled && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a.Text))
```

Can be simplified to

```
!a.IsEnabled || !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a.Text)
```

Comment: This only simplifies the code *per line*, you still need to write a check per control.

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify your handling of the logic by adding a helper extension method:

```
private static bool IsDisabledOrNotEmpty(this TextBox tb) {
    return !tb.IsEnabled || !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text);
}
```

Now you can rewrite your logic as follows:

```
bool ok =
    a.IsDisabledOrNotEmpty()
&&  b.IsDisabledOrNotEmpty()
&&  c.IsDisabledOrNotEmpty()
&&  (a.IsEnabled || b.IsEnabled || c.IsEnabled)
&&  d.IsDisabledOrNotEmpty()
&&  f.IsDisabledOrNotEmpty();
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `IsDisabledOrNotEmpty`?